# How to relocate/shade python packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependency-management, package-managers, python-packaging

I'm looking for a python package manager that has the same 'package relocation' feature as:

- maven-shade-plugin:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html

OR

- gradle-shadow-plugin:

https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/relocation/

it is important for any diamond package dependencies that has version conflict. Where can I find a package manager that supports it?

**UPDATE**: If it is still missing, then how much effort does it take to implement one?

Comment: The internal module resolution of python does not include versions in the module name, so changing the reference between different versions of the same package for a running interpreter is, out of the box, not possible. And if you do force it in runtime by hacking into `sys.modules`, you just move the goalpost to "is it possible to install two different versions of a package into the same python env?", to which the answer is an even stronger no. If you have to rely on a strange version of a package for some library, the usual solution is to vendor it within. Is that at all an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

According to the accepted solution in [this](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-does-the-julia-1-0-pkg-handle-diamond-dependencies/19558/4), diamond dependency will not happen.

Think about this: A (your project) requires B and C. Both B and C requires different versions of D.

With setup.py of A properly list the required version of B and C, pip will auto-deduce the version of D (or fails with an error).

For example, you need version 4 of B and version 3 of C. Version 4 of B requires >= 4 of D and version 3 of C requires >=3 of D. If that's the case, a proper version (4) of D will be installed.

If Version 4 of B requires >= 4 of D and version 3 of C requires < 4 of D, pip install will already fails. As a developer, you will know it in advance and try to use version 3.5 of B etc.

Also, [the document here](https://medium.com/@jimjh/managing-dependencies-in-python-applications-b9c93dda98c2) lists their internal process inspired by maven's shading. It may be of use to you (unfortunately, their method is manual and does not have a plugin/tool like you requested).

Comment: There is no version 3.5. Try to write one yourself? Good luck upgrading other's dynamically-typed legacy heirloom code.

Also, if it fails on installation and cannot be repaired, it already happened

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link, which indeed provides a promising direction, hope it can be made more autonomous by a package manage any time

Comment: "or fails with an error" - The idea of shading is that it provides a way to avoid the error by allowing multiple versions of a dependency at once via naming (that of course has to be reflected in your code). Python doesn't have any solutions for this?